# How do I place an element in front of the camera, facing it regardless of where it is?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have this simple scene with a "tooltip" entity composed of some data, I'd like to know how to position it in front of the camera. The tooltip will have to face certain points a few meters away so the user can see it. It must obey camera direction (it can be gathered by calculating it from previousPoint to nextPoint where the camera will move), but only y axis (can't be tilted or anything like that).I tried digging through math but couldn't understand good enough to employ a solution for this little project; I appreciate all the help!

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var camera = document.getElementById("cameraS");
  var tt = document.getElementById("ttS");

  var cameraPos = camera.getAttribute('position');
  var ttPos = tt.getAttribute('position');

  tt.setAttribute('position', cameraPos);
  tt.setAttribute('rotation', {'y': -90});
}, 5000);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6sLxwcd/)

EDIT

I made an image showing what I'm after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWEGQ.jpg
I have point A and point B; the camera will play an animation moving from previous point to the next, and upon reaching there the tooltip will be displayed a few meters away from the point (box) so we can see it. It must take camera orientation into consideration but it must be perpendicular to the ground (can't be tilted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command THREE.Object.lookAt(THREE.Vector3); that will rotate an object (assuming (0.0,1.0,0.0) is up) to face a vector. You can use this to have it face your camera.

If you only want Y rotation, you can copy the current rotation, then do look at, then copy the rotation.x and rotation.z from the previous frame rotation copy - so that way it'll only correct the y with .lookAt because you reset x and z.

Comment: This worked nearly perfect for me, the only part missing is having the position set up in front of the camera. By this image you can see the tootltip is correctly facing the camera regardless of where the camera is facing (1/3), the tooltip object is also preserving Y axis even if I tilt the camera (2/3); only part missing is positioning, I just tried setting the position but it went awkward: http://imgur.com/a/p1gN0

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6sLxwcd/2/ relevant code starts at JavaScript line 8.

Comment: to put something between two objects, you get a difference vector which is difference = p1-p2; normalize that vector, multiply it by the scalar distance you want it (either from the camera or from the target object), and then add p2 to it. If you want it fixed distance from the camera, then p2 is the camera. if you want it a fixed distance from the target object, then p2 is the target object. But the question is really unclear, so maybe you want a different behavior

Comment: I also wanted to *place* the tooltip in front of the camera, a few meters way actually ("away" as in a little away but in front of it so the user can see it). I'm sure there's some math involved to be able to get the camera direction and somehow use it in order to place correctly in front of the camera and looking at it (the camera). I'm terribly bad at explaining sorry.

Comment: if you want it to be stuck to the camera, so that it remains in front of the camera, you can add it to the camera as a child using THREE.Object3D.add(THREE.Object3D). Then the camera moves or rotates, the tooltip will maintain its relationship to the camera

Comment: That's where it gets tricky because if I append it as a child it will move with the camera, but I just want the position to be set once. The tooltip will be like a banner that will float in a given position when the camera lands on that position, and that's it. Then, I can rotate to check my surroundings while leaving the tooltip at that place, like a panel. The position and orientation will both be set once, based on camera, and will remain there.

Comment: see previous comment on how to position something between two objects. You know where camera will be and target will be. The tooltip position is then p1-p2 normalized multiplied by your desired tooltip distance plus p2. read above comment

Comment: Ok, I tried in that order and it shows differently now... I'm thinking there's something to do with rotation. I did: obtain direction by subtracting tooltip position from camera position, normalized this vector, obtained distance from tooltip to camera, multiplied normalized vector by this scalar. It pushed tooltip away somehow. Fiddle proof: https://jsfiddle.net/w6sLxwcd/3/ Image proof: http://imgur.com/a/a1qgY

Comment: Found an answer! This ties directly with matrix stuff, which (as you most surely must know by now) I am not good at. I followed an idea from this other SO and somehow it fit the purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910120/three-js-place-an-object-in-rotating-cameras-fov -------------------------------------------- I just did tooltip.object3D.position.applyMatrix4( camera.object3D.matrixWorld ); before doing your suggested lookAt operations and somehow it worked (I'd love to know why though)

Comment: JSFiddle proof: https://jsfiddle.net/w6sLxwcd/4/embedded/#Result --- since Y axis won't change (it's always "on the ground") it served my purpose for now. :)

Comment: I would be very hesitant to muck around with matrices or quaternions, and would encourage you to figure out how to do this using position and rotation specifically because it's too opaque to easily understand or tweak.

Comment: You were right... subsequent transformations mess up even further. :/